# Asterisk, Call next agent if present will refuse a call

Tags: queue, asterisk

I have a queue with few agents and leastrecent as strategy and timeout is set up on 10(sec). When phone ring and agent push 'busy' button i will that asterisk ring to next free agent without waiting sets up timeout.

It is possible to set up?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in queue configuration:

```
timeoutrestart=yes
ringinuse=no
```